# npm start & npm run build not working | React App

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start, npm-run

Commands `npm start`  &  `npm run build` are not working and give the following error messages (some phrases are in russian, please use translator if required):

from `npm start`

```
> react-cc-try2@0.1.0 start C:\Users\liana\Documents\My stuff\Webdev\Practice Projects & Courses\react-cc-try2
> react-scripts start

"Courses\react-cc-try2\node_modules\.bin\" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\liana\Documents\My stuff\Webdev\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1        
npm ERR! react-cc-try2@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-cc-try2@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\liana\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-28T23_50_41_165Z-debug.log
```

from `npm run build`

```
> react-cc-try2@0.1.0 build C:\Users\liana\Documents\My stuff\Webdev\Practice Projects & Courses\react-cc-try2
> react-scripts build

"Courses\react-cc-try2\node_modules\.bin\" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\liana\Documents\My stuff\Webdev\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'    
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-cc-try2@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-cc-try2@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\liana\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-28T23_51_00_496Z-debug.log
```

I've tried reinstalling everything, created a blank react app, nothing changed, absolutely. I have to use  `node node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js`  in order to start my local server and it works just fine, but this is not normal, I need a solution. Please help.

Comment: please share your package.json file as well as the npm version you are using and your OS

Comment: Try deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling it again,rm rf node_modules && npm i,if this doesn't work check your script in package.json file

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your `package.json` file:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
```

},